# PATH is different when echoed to Java console from Applet than when echoed in CMD

Tags: windows, path, cmd.exe

When running a Java applet from IE or Firefox, the Applet is echoing out the PATH variable to the Java Console, however it adds to the front of the PATH the location to the browser. This is not defined in my system environment variable, or user variable so where could it be finding this to add? When I echo the PATH manually from cmd I do not have the location of the browser at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser probably adds it itself.

Environment is specific to process. It is *inherited* from parent process when the process starts, but each process may modify it and pass it modified to the processes it starts. Just like when use use `set` in `cmd.exe` which also applies only to that instance of `cmd.exe` and all processes started from it.

The settings in "computer management" are simply default values passed to processes started by the login shell (the explorer instance handling start menu and desktop).

And note, that when you modify that settings, they *won't* apply to already running processes. Because they already have their copy of environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is also registry keys, where each application (executable name in fact) can define addition to PATH variable. Example

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe]
"Path"="C:\..."
```

And the same in HKEY_CURRENT_USER too.